# Swift - Retrieving subviews

Tags: xcode, swift, subviews

In my application I am adding labels to the view and then I am attempting to clear particular labels from the view when a button is clicked and am running into an error when trying to retrieve the subviews:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBAction func btnAddTask_Click(sender: UIButton){

          var subViews = self.subviews.copy()

    }
 }
```

I get the error:

'FirstViewController' does not have a member named 'subviews'

How can I get the subviews of the current view?

Comment: `self.view.subviews`?

Comment: I have tried this and get this error: '[AnyObject]' does not have a member named 'copy'

Comment: Arrays always copy in Swift.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`UIViewController` doesn't have a `subviews` property. It has a `view` property, which has a `subviews` property:

```
for subview in self.view.subviews {
   // Manipulate the view
}
```

But typically this is not a good idea. You should instead put the labels you want into an `IBOutletCollection` and iterate over that. Otherwise you've very tied to the exact set of subviews (which may change).

To create the `IBOutletCollection`, select all the labels you want in IB, and control-drag them to the source code. It should ask if you want to make a collection array. (Note that there is no promise on the order of this array.)

Comment: thanks.  This does work. I will look at your suggestion for using IBOutletCollection

Comment: I am dynamically creating the labels, so I'll need to figure out how to add the labels to the collection from the source code. Thanks again

Comment: Just put them in an array property as you create them.

Comment: Thanks, Rob, That's how I'm doing it.

Answer (score 11):

For find all subviews from your view you can use this code:

```
for subview in self.view.subviews {
   // Use your subview as you want
}
```

But for use it, you must identify view what you need. You can mark any element, what you create, with special Identifier like this:

```
myButton.restorationIdentifier = "mySpecialButton";
```

And after that you can find your element use this structure:

```
for view in view.subviews {
                if (view.restorationIdentifier == "mySpecialButton") {
                    print("I FIND IT");
                    view.removeFromSuperview();
                }
            }
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Hacky elegance:

1. Get the position of the click.
2. Retrieve the view with hitTest.
3. Differentiate the view with accessibilityIdentifier.

accessibilityIdentifier is developer facing and was intended for UI Automation.

Swift 4

```
@objc func handleTap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let positionInView = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)
    let hitTestView = view?.hitTest(positionInView, with: nil)
    print("hitTestView: \(hitTestView?.accessibilityIdentifier)")
}
```